# Clarification on StringBuilder reference and methods execution order

Tags: java, reference, stringbuilder

This piece of code

```
    StringBuilder b1=new StringBuilder("hello");
    b1.append(b1.append("!"));
    System.out.println("b1 = "+b1);
```

will print

```
    b1 = hello!hello!
```

because the inner `append` is executed first and modifies the object `b1`; then the outer `b1` is evaluated (it is equal to `hello!` now) and the same string is appended to it. So

1. inner expression is executed
2. original object gets modified
3. outer expression is executed on modified object

But now, why does this code throw a `NullPointerException`?

```
    StringBuilder s1=null;
    StringBuilder s2=new StringBuilder("world");
    try{s1.append(s1=s2.append("!"));}
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    System.out.println("s1 = "+s1+"\ns2 = "+s2+"\n");
```

and prints

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    s1 = world!
    s2 = world!
```

I was expecting the reference `s1` to be pointing at the object referenced by `s2` *before* the outer `append` gets executed.

In some way, assigning `b1.append("!");` affects the "outer" `b1`, but `s1=s2.append("!")` doesn't. I know it's due to the fact that in the first case I'm modifing the object, while in the second I'm modifing the reference but... what's the order in which values/references/methods are evaluated and executed?

## Edit

Same thing happens with arrays:

```
    int[] y = { 0, 0, 0 };
    try {y[y[0] = 2] = 4;} 
    catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    System.out.println("y = "+Arrays.toString(y)+"\n");
```

prints

```
    y = [2, 0, 4]
```

while

```
    int[] x1 = null;
    int[] x2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    try {x1[(x1=x2)[0]] = 0;} 
    catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    System.out.println("x1 = "+Arrays.toString(x1)+"\nx2 = "+Arrays.toString(x2));
```

prints

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    x1 = [1, 2, 3]
    x2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified in the JLS 15.12.4.:

> If form is ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier, then:
>
> - If the invocation mode is static, then there is no target reference. The ExpressionName is evaluated, but the result is then
>     discarded.
> - Otherwise, the target reference is the value denoted by ExpressionName.

and

> As part of an instance method invocation (§15.12), there is an
>   expression that denotes the object to be invoked. This expression
>   appears to be fully evaluated before any part of any argument
>   expression to the method invocation is evaluated.

So in the line `s1.append(s1=s2.append("!"));` `s1` (before `.append(s1 = ...)`) is evaluated first before the argument expression `s1=s2.append("!")`. So the `null` reference is remembered as the target reference before `s1` is changed to refer to the StringBuilder `s2` instance.

Then the argument expression is evaluated so `s1=s2.append("!")` is executed. But it remembered the target reference before, so the `append` method is invoked on the `null` reference, and the result of the invocation throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ok but then here `b1.append(b1.append("!"));` I would expect the outer `b1` to be evaluated as equal to `hello`, then executing the inner statement and resulting in `hellohello!`

Comment: @LuigiCortese `b1.append("!");` does not return a new instance. So the reference is still the same.

Comment: Uhm... and why does it make a diffence...? I mean, if the rule is that *outer reference is evaluated before inner expression*, I don't understand why I souldn't have `hellohello!`. Quite confused!

Comment: @LuigiCortese In `b1.append(b1.append("!"));` let's say, before the method call, that the `b1` reference is at the offset 0x10 in the memory. So it first remembers that it will have to execute the method on the reference at 0x10 in the memory. Then `b1.append("!")` is evaluated. As `StringBuilder` is mutable, this also modify the instance located at 0x10 to have the content `"hello!"`, but it does not change the reference! Then the method that accepts a `CharSequence` as parameter is invoked to append the content. As a result, you get `"hello!hello!"`.

Comment: I think I got it. Could we say that in both examples the outer *reference* (not the object) is evaluated, i.e. the "address" of the object, not the object itself? this would explain why, when the outer reference gets evaluated to `null`, nothing can change the object located at address... *[null]*! Am I right?

Comment: @LuigiCortese Yes you can think of it that way: it's like taking a photo of where the reference is before evaluating the argument list (oh I'm not good at analogy so this might be subjective ;) ). To illustrate my intent (and also this is what happen with your arrays example, in the second case `x1` and `x2` refers to the same reference after), if you look at http://ideone.com/1Ks0Yo you will see that you get a NPE, even if the reference is changed in the argument list of the method invocation.

Comment: Sure, that recalls my first example. Thanks for enlightening me =)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the byte code in your example,

```
   0: aconst_null
   1: astore_1
   // Comment: null is stored to s1.
   2: new           #18                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   5: dup
   6: ldc           #20                 // String world
   8: invokespecial #22                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  11: astore_2
  // Comment: new StringBuilder is stored to s2.
  12: aload_1
  // Comment: s1 (which is null) is loaded for method call.
  13: aload_2
  // Comment: s2 is loaded for method call.
  14: ldc           #25                 // String !
  16: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  19: dup
  20: astore_1
  // Comment: s2.append() return value is stored in s1.
  21: invokevirtual #31                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  // Comment: append() method is called on already loaded s1 value (which is null).
  24: pop
  25: return
```

If you read through my comments in the code, you will know that `null` is loaded for invoking the method `append()`.

Let's take another example,

```
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("world");
    s1.append(s1 = s2.append("!"));
    System.out.println(s1);
```

This will only print `world!`. Even though you would expect `world!world!`.

That's because you are reassining the value of `s1` after it's loaded for method call. Which means on the method call the reassigned value will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the Java interpreter first tries to locate (not evaluate, just locate) the method, in this case `s1.append()`. My guess is that it does it to add the method pointer to the stack. To do this, it needs to know the exact class of the object `s1`, so it dereferences it. Because `s1` is null, this results in the `NullPointerException`.

This happens even before the arguments are evaluated, hence the fact that `s1` is still `null`.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132128/1654764) lists the different steps that occur in our `s1.append` call :

> 1. The object pointer is used to reference the object, and from there the Class object.
> 2. The method pointer is located in the Class object. (The lookup to convert method name to method index was largely done when the class
>      was loaded, so this is basically just an array index operation.)
> 3. Generally some sort of a "mark" is pushed onto the JVM stack. This would contain the caller's instruction pointer, and a pointer to the
>      base of his stack. (Lots of different implementations here.)
> 4. The method's definition is consulted to see how many local vars are needed. That many blank elements are pushed onto the stack.
> 5. The object ("this") pointer is stored in local var 0, and any parms are stored in 1,2,3... as appropriate.
> 6. Control is transferred to the called method.

The `NullPointerException` occurs at step 1.

Answer (score 0):

in `b1.append(b1.append("!"));` not inner append it's executed first. Java will call first append then will evaluate the parameter `b1.append("!")` for this call that will modify the `b1` object . Here `s1.append(s1=s2.append("!"));` will call
`s1.append()` method but because `s1` it's null, will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: in the second example `s1=s2.append("!")` is actually executed, and modifies the object and the reference `s1`

Comment: but at the moment when you call `s1.append()` `s1` is null

Comment: Obviously. My question is: if `s1=s2.append("!")` is executed before `s1.append()`, why in this second statement `s1` is null?