# How does multithreading method invocation work

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using java.

I have an instance a of class A which has a public method foo() running and 2 other threads - threadB and threadC, all running at the same time.

here's class A

```
public class A {
    int val = 0
    public void foo(int incValue) {
        a += incValue;
    }
    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        MyThread a = new MyThread(this);
        new Thread(a).start();
        MyThread b = new MyThread(this);
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
}
```

here's the thread definition for threadB and threadC:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    A main = null;
    public MyThread(A main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
    public callFoo(int incValue) {
        main.foo(incValue);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //valToInc can be a value from a GUI form.
        callFoo(valToInc);
    }
}
```

If in threadB invokes callFoo(1) and threadC invokes callFoo(3) at the same time, then:
 - Which thread will be able to call the method first?
 - What is the result of the val in main class after both executions?
 - Will the execution of the method for each thread happen concurrently or one after another?

Comment: There are literally whole books on that topic. This question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No idea - show some code. Without code, this question is far too broad.

Comment: *"...how does java handle this situation?"* By calling the method in all of the threads, possibly overlapping, unless there's some synchronization you've included in `foo` (by default, there is none, and calls can completely overlap).

Comment: Define "handle" and "situation."  At the machine level, executable code is unmodifiable (usually) so the code just executes in each thread, independently.  There's really nothing to it.

Comment: generally speaking: objects are placed on the heap, which means all threads share the same objects. so threadB and threadC will enter the same instance of foo() and will encounter the same state of this instance (i.e. same variable values). so when threadB will modify something, threadC will see it. anything thats on the heap is shared by threads. anything thats on the stack is private to a thread (each thread has its own stack). but yes, this question in general is too broad.

Comment: thanks everyone, I have modified my questions.

Comment: With your example, I think the only answer is **badly**. Congratulations, you have written a race hazard generator. Furthermore `MyThread` is missing a `run()` method, so your code doesn't compile.

Comment: So how do I fix this? I want to make sure I can control the value of val

Comment: Books have been written on the topic of thread safety, this is something that is far too broad for a question on this site. I would begin by [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). The I would do some [more reading](http://jcip.net/). At that point you should have enough of an understanding to write some code. Not before. Concurrency is difficult, very difficult. It cannot be tested to check correctness; you must write correct code to begin with.

Comment: thanks! I'll keep this in mind. I had learned about threading and all that but in a very theoretical way~ all those things, like using semaphore and mutex, but now that I have to actually put it to work with Java, I'm kinda at a lost...

Comment: That code won't compile:  You can't use `this` in a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in how the JVM will invoke two methods "in parallel".

In other words: if you want to know what happens when a method is called, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131892/what-happens-after-a-method-is-called-in-java).

When a method is called "twice" in parallel, then that whole thing ... just happens *twice*!

Things become interesting when that method is making **updates** on that class, or in other objects! (like changing a field of your object, or appending a value to a list, ... )

You see, the real complexity of multi-threading is **not** about running some code in parallel. The **real issue** is what happens to "shared data".

If you find my answer to general; sorry - that is probably the best you can expect for such a generic question.

Comment: Thanks; I put some examples in my answer to make that more clear!

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I was wondering what would happen if those two invocations modify a field in the class instance.

Comment: However, if I my methods do not modify any values. Say, in class A I a string list of user and a method bool foo2(String name)  that will return true if the parameter matches a name in the list. That's it, no modification is made to the actual list. Then are there any chances that I might get the wrong results if I call this method from many threads at the  exact same time?

Comment: No. If information is read that never changes.... then order doesn't matter! Like in: imagine a projector that puts a static picture on the wall. Would it matter how many people are looking at that picture?!

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, I've found quite a useful link for anyone that might run into the same problem as I did. It shows how to use the synchronized key word in java [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html)

Comment: final hint: the first comment from yshavit really nails it - this isn't only about the *synchronized* keyword. Or, in other words - when you follow your own (nice!) link - all the chapters on java concurrency deal with multi-threading topics. In essence, all of that can be relevant and should be "known" and understood by somebody dealing with this topics!

Answer (score 0):

> If [] threadB invokes callFoo(1) and threadC invokes callFoo(3) at the same time, then: - Which thread will be able to call the method first?

Threads run independently of each other.  If there is no *synchronization* (there's none in your example), then any number of threads can be in calls to the same method at the same time.

Whenever a thread calls a method, it creates an *activation record* to hold all of the local variables and parameters of that method, and when several threads call the same method at the same time, each thread gets its own activation record.  The threads can neither communicate with one another through the args and locals, nor can they interfere with one another's use of the args and locals.

They can, of course communicate and interfere with each other through any shared objects, including objects that may be *referenced* by the args or the locals.